# How to use slicing to obtain data for a specific row/column?

Tags: python, function, numpy

I am having to write a function that when given an input (in this case, a year) will return only the data from that year, if that makes sense: I have written some of the function and given an idea the best I can to what I'm looking for:

```
def get_data(year):
    data = np.loadtxt(data.csv, delimiter=',', skiprows=1)
    year = int(year)
    # if the input year has no data, a value error must be raised
    #function returns the data for the input year
    #e.g. if the input year is on row 3, I need the fucntion to give the data for row 3 only.
```

any help/hints with this would be much appreciated because I'm lost on where to start. Any explanaitions would be great too as I don't really understand coding much yet.

Thanks!

Comment: You should be able to get the data through `data["year" == year]`, if your column name is "year".

Comment: What does `data` look like.  Given that `loadtxt` call, I expect it is a 2d array of floats.  Is one of the columns the `year` one?  You/we need to more information about the `csv`.

Comment: @hpaulj yes, my bad, the data has multiple columns one of which is the year one, thank you for the reply